# Expanded Menu Showing Extra Spacing

Tags: css, menuitem

There seems to be a gap when clicking any menu ite that has a child. Ive tried everything but still cant seem to get rid of it. Its worse when you view it at a screen resolution that would appear on a mobile. I cant really move on till i fix it so all help appreciated. tx.

```
<div class="region region-primary-menu">
<ul class="menu">
<li class="first leaf">
<li class="leaf">
<li class="leaf">
<li class="leaf">
<li class="expanded active-trail menu-item-preferred">
<a class="active-trail menu-item-preferred active" title="Football betting for fiends" href="/football-betting">Football</a>
<ul class="menu">
</li>
<li class="last collapsed">
</ul>
</div>

#primary {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #0A0A0A;
    border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
    font-family: 'Oswald',Arial Narrow,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 77px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    top: 45px;
    z-index: 1;
}
#primary ul {
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#primary ul li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#primary ul li a {
    border-right: 1px dashed #222222;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
#primary ul li a:hover {
    color: #AB0000;
}
#primary li.expanded, #primary li.collapsed, #primary li.leaf {
    list-style: none outside none !important;
}
#primary ul.menu ul {
    font-size: 10px;
}
#primary ul.menu ul a {
    color: #666666;
    font-size: 10px;
}
#primary ul.menu ul a:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

a [WORKING EXAMPLE](http://betmental.com/football-betting) can be found there.

Comment: Should we click all links on your website to find out which menu you talk about?

Comment: sorry Morpheus im a bit shell shocked today after 24hrs of 'arsing about' with my theme. Its the 'football' link top right. Youll see the child menu items from there and the big gap to the right of football. Nearly bed time for me soz

Comment: Which gap? To the right of the `football` menu item or to the bottom?

Comment: to the right Morpheus. Id prefer the 1st level (football, sports, poker etc) to always just stay the same width between items be they open or closed. I appreciate you having a lok morpheus as ive had to give up after many hours of trying. its making a mess for my whole top part on mobiles so i cant really move on till its sorted. tx

Comment: I think you best bet would be to go with absolute positioning for your sub menu. Something like this -> http://dabblet.com/gist/2792978